# Homomorphism between two algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

So I know from ring theory that if we have a homomorphism $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ then it must be the case that for some ideal $I \subseteq A$ we have $\phi(I) \subseteq B$ and $\phi(I)$ is an ideal of $B$ (of course, this assumes that $\phi$ is surjective).

My question is is the same true of homomorphisms between two algebras? For instance, between $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathbb{C}$, is it true that all homomorphisms map $$\begin{bmatrix}0 &0\\0& 0\end{bmatrix} \mapsto 0 $$ and $$\begin{bmatrix}a &b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\mapsto a+b+c+d,$$ since these are the only two ideals of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathbb{C}$ respectively?

Answer (score 3):

It is a standard exercise to show that $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is a so called *simple* algebra, i.e. it has no non-trivial ideals (the same holds for all matrix algebras over any field). This places a severe constraint on all algebra (or ring) homomorphisms 
$\phi:M_2(\mathbb{C})\to \mathbb{C}.$ Namely $\ker\phi$ has to be an ideal. There are only two choices. The kernel can't be all of the matrix algebra, because then $\phi(I)\neq1$. The kernel cannot be trivial either, because then $\phi$ would be injective. If $\phi$ were injective, then $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ would be isomorphic to a subring of $\mathbb{C}$. Consequently it would be both commutative and have no zero-divisors :-)

The conclusion: There are no algebra/ring homomorphisms $M_2(\mathbb{C})\to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Aha, it was the injective property that I couldn't make sense of in my head! I had scratchings on paper that showed that $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ (and $\mathbb{C}$) was simple; indeed I am also aware that $\mathbb{C}$ and $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ are Morita equivalent (I don't know enough category theory to fully appreciate this, but I do know this means it is essentially a direct copy of a few $\mathbb{C}$'s. Unfortunately, apparently my brain then decided to turn off and accept that $\phi$ (and _not_ $ker(\phi)$) had to be an ideal! thanks for the help.